# Jenkins: Parameterize triggered job's name OR Link two multi-configuration jobs

Tags: jenkins, multi-configuration

My company produces a product in multiple flavors, on Linux and Android for example. On Jenkins, these are produced on a multi-configuration job.

I need to build a wrapper to the product on a different job. My manager insists that the wrapper and the product be built on separate jobs.

My problem is, I cannot seem to be able to pass axis variables.
Using the parameterized build plugin, "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" doesn't take parameters (how terribly ironic), and axis variables seem to be ignored (see example image).

Does anyone have a viable solution?

[jenkins_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUb60.png)

Comment: From the example image:
Are you sure you are providing correct job name?
Does the downstream is "parameterized job" having all the 3 params?

Can you put down how downstream job is getting executed?

Comment: 1) 100% sure, it works if I don't use variables. Variables won't expand. 2) Yes, it does. 3) All valid possible child jobs are executed, I have debug filtered out using "Combination Filter". See image: https://imgur.com/a/WVpKY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my own answer for now:

It seems that linking matrix jobs on child job basis is impossible (or impractical. You could theoretically make a huge flexible publish if/else, but I didn't try that).

Instead I now build the whole second matrix once the first matrix is done. I trigger it like this:
[Triggering the matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChOYK.png)

And I copy the artifacts like this:
[Copying the artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4P78.png)